# White background during app launch

Tags: android, background, styles, themes

I want to get rid of the white color during the short period when my app is launching but the content isn't displayed, yet.

My main activity is using a style (from the Manifest) that extends `@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` with the background set to `<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>`. Nowhere in my layout do I use a white background color, yet it appears for a brief moment during app launch.

In the HierarchyViewer I exported the layers and checked back that there is really no white solid in the layout hierarchy.

What setting controls the background color before the layout is drawn? Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's another background attribute in your theme - `windowBackground`, and you implicitly set it to white  by inheriting your style from `@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` (notice the `.Light.` part in the name).

You can either use dark version of theme or set it explicitly by including `windowBackground` in your style definition:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: How do you add custom color code to it rather than a predefined value?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use drawable. I created a theme for my spash screen like as below :)

```
<style name="SceneTheme.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SceneTheme.Light.NoActionBar.Transparent.StatusBar" parent="SceneTheme.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
</style>
```